# How to save nested attributes on a has many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am having some issues and i am a bit confused on the correct way to save nested attributes.

I have two models, locations and products and a join table called stock that joins those two models.

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :stocks
  has_many :products, :through => :stocks
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :stocks
  has_many :locations, :through => :stocks

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations
end

class Stock < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :product
end
```

and in my controller i have the following

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
    @product.stocks.build
    @locations = Location.all
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    if @product.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully saved..."
      redirect_to products_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong, please check the values you entered"
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end
```

But i think i got things wrong on how to do it, as nothing happens. What i want is when creating a product, to show all possible locations so that the user can select in which locations to state that this product should exists. Naturally this is tracked by the stock model.

anyone care to enlighten me?

**EDIT**: I made some changes to this,

my new view

```
<div class="input-field">
  <%= f.label :product_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true %>
</div>

<div class="input-field">
  <%= f.label :price %>
  <%= f.text_field :price, autofocus: true %>
</div>


<%= f.fields_for :stocks do |ff| %>
  <div class="input-field">
    <%= ff.collection_select :location_id, Location.all, :id, :structured_location , {:prompt => "Please Select Locations for Product"}, {multiple: true} %>
    <%= ff.label :locations %>
  </div>
<% end %>


<div class="row margin-top x-4">
  <div class="col s12 center-align">
    <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn wave-effect pink darken-1 btn-large" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

in product.rb model

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :stocks
  has_many :locations, :through => :stocks

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :stocks

end
```

Now i am able to select locations but when i push to products controller i get that location_id is not permitted

here are my strong params

```
def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit( :name,:price, {stocks_attributes: [:location_id]} )
  end
```

and here are the params being sent in console

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"751Z5I5nBwmYJwFeiXO3jyBnPxqr3Pdz0ohDpN96F0ybE9V4yeUgjt2QYDYZfNvWG4CAdhvGaxIaCmqD6Ka8qw==", "product"=>{"name"=>"Tires Cleaner", "price"=>"4", "stocks_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"location_id"=>["", "1"]}}}, "commit"=>"Update"}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'as nothing happens'? Error? No data saved? etc

Comment: Your strong params need to be this too: params.require(:product).permit(:name,:price, locations_attributes: [:id, :venue])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's a has_many relationship, you need to tell strong params it is an array you're sending and then the location specific attributes. Also, so it works when you edit later on, I would also permit the :id field:

```
params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price, stocks_attributes: [:id, location_id: []])
```

This will allow you to post an array of venues and then when you write you update action later you can also edit the venue (without the :id allowed, it will duplicate the row).

Comment: hey i still have a problem while using this, it says that the parameter :venue is not permitted, why? :S

Comment: Can you update your question with the params you see posted in yours rail server console?

Comment: ok if you could please read my changes from EDIT and below thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer. However, it's odd it's posting ["", "1] for location_id, I think the form might be slightly incorrect. I'll look that over too.

Comment: Hey this worked thanks! However i have another "issue". I want to create multiple stock records in database, linking the product_id, with the various location_ids, so if i select two location_ids to create two Stock records with same product_id but different location_id, is that possible this way or? Hmm dunno whats wrong with it ( ["","1"] )

Comment: I'm glad that worked.Your next question sounds like a separate question really - post another one with all the relevant model information and more detail on what you want to do and link to it here.

Comment: Yes records are saved all well expect from location_id, since its an array it is not added to the Stock record and thats why i asked you about it. Guess i will make another question off of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you need to nest the attributes of the locations relation in the product params, for example:

```
params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price, {stocks_attributes: [:id, :location_id]})
```

Comment: hey thanks for answer, however i get the same error as i responded to RichardAE...

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou That is because your new question is completely different to the original question asked, the attributes in the view and relations have changed completely, I have edited my answer.

Comment: the question hasn't changed really, its just i had another problem elsewhere and you guys pointed it out to me.

Comment: Yeah I meant to say the example code, sorry lol, but glad you got it all sorted now!

Answer (score 0):

It is easier if the relationship between Location and Product is direct. I don't see the importance of the stock model. A location has many products and a product has many locations. Therefore,

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :locations
end
```

You need a migration to create the stock table. Then your nested form should be `

```
<%= f.fields_for :locations do |ff| %>
  <div class="input-field">
    <%= ff.collection_select :id, Location.all, :id, :structured_location , {:prompt => "Please Select Locations for Product"}, {multiple: true} %>
<%= ff.label :locations %>
  </div>
<% end %>`
```

I hope it helps.

`

Comment: Hey what you might forget is that this way you cannot have extra fields on the stock table, which i have. isn't that right?

Comment: I thought you don't have extra fields, from your form I don't see one

Comment: yeah i neglected them my bad, thansk for effort though ;o